# When to specify Dispatchers.xxx for coroutines in classes

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I often create classes that have functions that contain a coroutine. It isn't always clear whether the function is being used by some component that is bound to the UI or whether it's doing background work that is more IO oriented. Here's an example:

```
fun myFunction() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
       // Do something
    }
}
```

In this example, no Dispatcher.MAIN or Dispatchers.IO is specified. Is this the correct way to do this? Does the coroutine use the scope of whatever the calling client happens to be using? Should I only specify a dispatcher when I know definitively that I need a specific scope?

Answer (score 2):

**`GlobalScope` binds the lifecycle of the Coroutine to the lifecycle of the application itself**. 
Which means Coroutine started from this scope would continue to live until one of two things occur

- Coroutine completes its job.
- The Application itself is killed.

*Using async or launch on the instance of **GlobalScope is highly discouraged.***

> No Dispatcher.MAIN or Dispatchers.IO is specified. Is this the correct way to do this?

Yea, why not? If the work inside coroutine is not related to either ***UI*** or ***IO*** go for it.

> Should I only specify a dispatcher when I know definitively that I
>   need a specific scope?

To answer this, let's first see the definition of `launch` from docs,

```
 fun CoroutineScope.launch(
     context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
     start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
     block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit ): Job (source)
```

The `Dispatcher` which we are talking about is a kind of `CoroutineContext`. As you can see in the definition if the `CoroutineContext` is not mentioned(which means we have not mentioned the `Dispatcher` too) it is by default set to `EmptyCoroutineContext` which internally uses Dispatchers.Default and this is what docs say about it,

> The default CoroutineDispatcher that is used by all standard builders
>   like launch, async, etc if neither a dispatcher nor any other
>   ContinuationInterceptor is specified in their context.
>
> It is backed by a shared pool of threads on JVM. By default, the
>   maximum number of threads used by this dispatcher is equal to the
>   number of CPU cores, but is at least two.

So even if you forget to mention the Dispatcher, Scheduler will pick any random available thread from the pool and hand it the Coroutine. But make sure that not to initiate any **`UI`** related work without mentioning the Dispatcher.

Comment: You wrote: "Using async or launch on the instance of GlobalScope is highly discouraged." - Says who? The official documentation on coroutines completely disagrees with that statement. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html

Comment: Please check this https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you must differentiate the *scope* from the *context* and *dispatcher*.

Coroutine *scope* is primarily about the lifecycle of the coroutine and deals with the concept of structured concurrency. It may have a default dispatcher, which would be the one logically associated with the object to which you tie the coroutine's lifecycle. For example, if you scope a coroutine to an Android activity, the default dispatcher will be UI.

Coroutine *context* refers to a dispatcher. The context should change during the coroutine's execution, as the logic inside requires it. Typically, you will use `withContext` to temporarily switch dispatchers in order to avoid blocking the UI thread. You will *not* typically launch the whole coroutine in the thread pool, unless all of it should run on a background thread (e.g., no UI interaction).

Second, the choice of dispatcher should be collocated with the code that requires a specific one. It should happen within the function that deals with a given concern, like making REST requests or DB operations. This once again reinforces the practice not to decide on dispatchers when launching the coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

`GlobalScope` is an `EmptyCoroutineScope` and all coroutines launched with this scope are like demo threads. They cannot be canceled and remain active until their completion. I suggest implementing a specific scope e not using `GlobalScope` in order to control all the coroutines that are launched. The `GlobalScope` use the `Dispatchers.Default` as the default dispatcher and in your case you always create coroutines in the default dispatcher.

Comment: "They cannot be canceled...". Hate to inform you, but GlobalScope.launch is cancelable.

Comment: I hate to inform you ;) but you can only cancel the coroutine if you keep a reference to the job, but GlobalScope has no associated job and therefore you cannot trace all the coroutines together. Usually you should use a scope that has a 'lifetime' and that can terminate its children when it dies. See the GlobalScope documentation.